# Methods for Serialization never called

Tags: java, serialization

i need to serialize data from a static HashMap. I need this static data because i have no instance of the class in which this map exist.
I implement the serializable interface and build this two methods:

```
private synchronized void writeObject( ObjectOutputStream out ) throws IOException
{
    System.out.println("start serialization ...");

    Collection<TaskUpdateListener> tasks = listeners.values();
    out.writeInt( tasks.size() );
    for(TaskUpdateListener task : tasks)
    {
        out.writeObject( task );
    }   
}

private synchronized void readObject( ObjectInputStream in ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    System.out.println("start deserialization ...");

    int size = in.readInt();
    for( int index = 0; index < size; index++)
    {
        addTaskUpdateListener( (ComponentScheduleTable) in.readObject() );
    }   
}
```

But this methods are never called.
Has anybody the same problem or a solution for this one?

Comment: how are you using the class? Just looking at the serialization code is going to make it difficult to figure out why it's not being called.

Comment: Why not just serialize the HashMap?

Comment: The Class has only static methods and cache some user_id in a static variable.

Comment: show the code where you are attempting to serialize the class instance, and possibly more of the class.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Serialising an instance of a class wont serialise data (only) referenced through statics. Mutable statics are a very bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
private  void writeObject( ObjectOutputStream out ) throws IOException
    {

        System.out.println("start serialization ...");

        Collection<TaskUpdateListener> tasks = listeners.values();
        out.writeInt( tasks.size() );
        for(TaskUpdateListener task : tasks)
        {
            out.writeObject( task );
        }

  }
```

Synchronize keyword is not neccessary, method is called in synchronize block.

Comment: You welcome. But I think it will be working (synchronized keyword was dropped :) ). I remove both

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `synchronized`; the methods must be thread safe without this. If you need synchronization, you must implement it differently (for example with locks) to avoid deadlocks.

**[EDIT]** There can be two reasons why the methods are not called:

1. The signature isn't 100% correct
2. These instances are always marked as `transient`

Comment: This has also no effect. I find both variants on the web. But thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

> I need this static data because i have no instance of the class in
>   which this map exist.

That makes no sense. If you don't have an instance you can't get the map so you can't serialize it, and if the instance doesn't exist neither does the map.

Howver if you do magically have a reference to the map somehow, just serialize it, you don't need to write any `readObject`/`writeObject` methods to do so. Just call `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` with the map as argument, etc.